# Error in android/app/build.gradle while using Intellij Idea for Flutter

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, flutter

There are errors for Properties() and Gradleexception(). How can these be solved?

[image]

I even tried opening it in Android Studio also, but its not working even there. How do I proceed?

[image]

Comment: You should import corresponding classes into a build script. Can you build by Gradle from command line?

Comment: I dont know how to build by Gradle from command line. And how do I import the corresponding classes int a build script?

Comment: For those who are still trying to figure out what the problem is, don't waste your time thinking about it because this error does not cause a problem while we are running our application, its just for show. Also, it does not affect your app in any other way possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to edit gradle file properly - you have to open content of `android` folder as android project
I'm not sure about InteliJ Idea, but this is how it looks in Android Studio:

[image]

**UPD:**
Click on: `File` -> `Open...` -> then chose not `example_123` folder but `example_123\android` for open exactly android project

Comment: What changes will I have to make using the Android Studio to remove this error?

Comment: You just have to open `android` folder as android project. In you case you open flutter project and gradle file is shown incorrectly

Comment: I did that, but even in Android Studio those two are highlighted and error is being shown. How can I remove these errors after opening Android Studio?

Comment: Could you add screenshot from Android studio - How exactly do you open it?

Comment: You still open your flutter project in android studio. I've updated my answer - you have to open `example_123\android` folder

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Thanks!

Comment: @Devansh Baldwa glad it helped